# Why can't I log in to Apex Data Loader?

Tags: data-loader, login-errors, login, security-token, environment-hub

I created a new Partner EE org through the Environment Hub. Once it was live and I could log in to it I reset my security token (because I didn't have one) and started up Apex Data Loader. I went to log in to data loader like I have in the past - using the new username and my password+security token. If my password was "password" and my security token was 1234567890, I entered: password1234567890

However I get a message saying "Error logging in to Salesforce. Please check your username and password."

I have relogged in to Salesforce to verify that the username and password are correct. Login History doesn't show any attempts to log in. Is this potentially an issue with Environment Hub and it's new domain system? Does the system need more time to propagate? Why can't I log in to Data Loader?

Answer (score 1):

Wah-wah.

I forgot that the settings are keyed to a specific server host. Once I changed that to the right one it worked just fine. I of course thought to check the settings section right after I posted this.

Leaving this so others can learn from my folly.